# HTML form does not submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create a simple age calculator. At the moment the **current year** will populate but when you enter your **birth year** and click **submit** nothing happens.

```js
function aaa(){
    date=new Date();
    var y=date.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('ddd').value=y;
}

function display(){
    var c=document.getElementById('eee').getFullYear.value;
    //var aa= document.getElementById('eee').(this).('getDate').value;
    var e= y - c;
    {
      document.write("Ans="+e);
    }
    alret(e);
}
```

```html
<body onload="aaa();">
    <form name="xyz" method="post">
        CurrentDate:<input type="text" name="ddd" id="ddd"> 
        BirthDate:<input type="date" name="eee" id="eee">
        Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="display();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: *"can you have a google"* - you're joking, right?

Comment: by "google" i meant "look" sorry for confusion!

Comment: need to prevent form from submitting or it will always reload the page

Comment: Hi charlietfl - so change <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="display();"> ??

Comment: changed code to: <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="display()";> .... And not it doesnt delete the "birth yr" anymore but still not showing age..

Comment: There are more ways to submit a form than the submit button (e.g. press enter in the input field) and you shouldn't name a form control "submit" as it masks the form's submit method. Input type date is not supported by all browsers in use (not even some current versions). Calling *document.write* after the page has loaded will clear the **entire** document first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better for code review, but here goes:

```
<script language="javascript">
```

The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML5. Remove it.

```
function aaa()
```

Functions should have a meaningful name, e.g. *setYear*.

```
{
    date=new Date();
```

You should keep variables local with *var*.

```
    var y=date.getFullYear();

    document.getElementById('ddd').value=y;
```

You could just do:

```
  document.getElementById('ddd').value = new Date().getFullYear();

}
function display()
{
    var c=document.getElementById('eee').getFullYear.value;
```

Input type date isn't supported by all browsers, and that won't work anyway. If you are just using the difference in years (which will be incorrect by 1 year about half the time) then why not just ask for the year?

```
    var e= y - c;
    {
      document.write("Ans="+e);
    }
```

The block is redundant, and calling *document.write* after the load event will first clear the entire document (everything, including all scripts) and load a new document with just the content passed to *document.write*.

[...]

So a re-write might look like:

```js
function calcAge(element) {
  var form = element.form;
  form.age.value = form.currentYear.value - form.birthYear.value;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[0].currentYear.value = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<form>
  Current year: <input name="currentYear"><br>
  Birth year: <input name="birthYear"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calcAge(this)" value="Caluclate age"><br>
  Your age: <input name="age" readonly><br>
</form>
```

Note that every control in a form has a *form* property that references the form it's in. Also, form controls with a name are available as named properties of the form (hence a control named *submit* overwrites the submit method).

Answer (score 0):

- `document.getElementById('eee')` is a DOM element.
- `document.getElementById('eee').getFullYear` is, judging from your code, `undefined`.
- `document.getElementById('eee').getFullYear.value` should throw an error.

You were trying to read a property from an object which is (unfortunately) `undefined`, that's why your code doesn't work. Open console and see if there is a red line saying something like this:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined